# Groovy - to string that passes Eval.me

Tags: groovy

I would like to be able to turn strings to object back and forth in groovy.

For example

```
def mapString = "['guy':'mograbi']"
def myMap = Eval.me(mapString)
def savedString = myMap.toString()
def savedMap = Eval.me(savedString)
```

the last line fails because `toString` does not output a String I can evaluate.

How can I turn the map to a string I can evaluate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`inspect()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#inspect%28%29) method returns a parseable string.  Example:

```
def map = [guy:'mograbi']
def str = map.inspect()
def mapFromString = Eval.me(str)
assert map == mapFromString
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted, and it was fast too :)